# How to make the first row of a csv file the column names when loading into AWS Athena?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, relational-database, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am pipelining csv's from an S3 bucket to AWS's Athena using Glue and the titles of the columns are just the default 'col0', 'col1' etc, while the true titles of the columns are found in the first row entry. Is there a way, either in the pipeline process or in an early postgreSQL query, to make the first row entry the column names? Ideally avoiding directly hardcoding in the column names in the Glue crawler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373335/aws-glue-crawler-cannot-extract-csv-headers go through this.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html

Use `withHeader=True` while reading data using Glue Api